# How do I send tweets with flame sensor and ESP8266?

Tags: esp8266, communication, code-review, wireless, network

I want to send tweets with flame sensor and ESP8266. My flame sensor is digital. I think everything is good but it doesn't send.

This is my code:

```cpp
#define ag_ismi "SSID"
#define ag_sifresi "PASSWORD"
#define IP "184.106.153.149" //thingspeak.com IP address

int sensorPin = 8;
int smoke_level = HIGH;

void setup() {
  pinMode(sensorPin, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("AT");
  delay(3000);
  if (Serial.find("OK")) {
    Serial.println("AT+CWMODE=1");
    delay(2000);
    String baglantiKomutu = String("AT+CWJAP=\"") + ag_ismi + "\",\"" + ag_sifresi + "\"";
    Serial.println(baglantiKomutu);
    delay(5000);
  }
}

void loop() {
  smoke_level = digitalRead(sensorPin); // Arduino reads the value from the smoke sensor
  Serial.println(smoke_level);// prints just for debugging purposes, to see what values the sensor is picking up
  if (smoke_level == HIGH) {
    // if smoke level is greater than 500, the buzzer will go off
    sicaklik_yolla();
  }
  delay(20000);
}
void sicaklik_yolla() {
  Serial.println(String("AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"") + IP + "\",80");
  delay(1500);
  String tweet = "POST /apps/thingtweet/1/statuses/update HTTP/1.1\n";
  tweet += "Host: api.thingspeak.com\n";
  tweet += "Connection: close\n";
  tweet += "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\n";
  tweet += "Content-Length:67\r\n\r\napi_key=";
  tweet += String("MY API KEY");
  tweet += String("&status=");
  tweet += String("MY TWEET TEXT");
  Serial.print("AT+CIPSEND=");
  delay(100);
  Serial.println(tweet.length());
  if (Serial.find(">")) {
    Serial.println(tweet);
    Serial.println("AT+CIPCLOSE=0");
    delay(100);
  } else {
    Serial.println("AT+CIPCLOSE=0");
  }
}
```

This schema is old. Sensor connected to pin 8.

[image: old connection]

Answer (score 1):

I guess your baud rate and network connection with the wifi module is working fine. Have to say that it is a bit difficult to get the data sent to ThingSpeak with ESP8266. I actually did some experiments to get the data sent. The problem is actually with the delay. Adding a delay of 5000 ms between sending the tweet length and the tweet content sorts it out. You can use GET format. Check out [this Instructable](http://www.instructables.com/id/Distant-Weather-Monitoring-Using-Arduino-and-ESP82).